# Solving binomial theorem via induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, binomial-theorem

I'm trying to prove binomial theorem by induction, but I'm a little stuck. I would look at online resources as this problem has been done many times, but the version I am trying to prove the binomial theorem in a different form.

$$(1 + x)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^k$$

I'm mostly confused as to how I can make the left side be equivalent to a summation, any help is appreciated. Try to hint me along!

Comment: Probably the form most online resources use is $(a+b)^n$. Simply substitute $a = 1, b = x$ everywhere in the proof.

Comment: Note that $(1+x)^{n+1}=(1+x)\cdot (1+x)^n$ which by your induction hypothesis will be $(1+x)\cdot \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k\right)$.  Now... some frustrating shifting of indices and combining of terms later you should arrive at the result.  Remember your Paschal's identity: $\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}$

Comment: If you are still stuck, I suggest you use the [search function](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+theorem+induction) on this site to find duplicate answers, which there surely are dozens of for this question already.

Comment: After a couple hours of searching, I found a couple of  examples, but I received this problem with little background in algebraically manipulating summations. Using examples of the form $(a + b)^n$ won't work unfortunately, thanks for all your help!

Comment: I did not find a full answer, though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We show by induction the following is valid for $n\geq 0$
>   \begin{align*}
> (1 + x)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^k
> \end{align*}

**Base step: $n=0$**

> We have to show
>   \begin{align*}
> (1 + x)^0 = \sum_{k = 0}^{0} \binom{0}{k} x^k
> \end{align*}
>
> Since the left-hand side is $$(1+x)^0=1$$
>   and the right-hand side is $$\sum_{k = 0}^{0} \binom{0}{k} x^k=\binom{0}{0}x^0=1,$$ both sides are equal and the claim is valid for $n=0$.

**Induction hypothesis: $n=N$**

> We assume the validity of
>   \begin{align*}
> (1 + x)^N = \sum_{k = 0}^{N} \binom{N}{k} x^k\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

**Induction step: $n=N+1$**

> We have to show
>   \begin{align*}
> (1 + x)^{N+1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{N+1} \binom{N+1}{k} x^k
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> (1 + x)^{N+1} &= (1+x)(1+x)^N\tag{2}\\
> &=(1+x)\sum_{k = 0}^{N} \binom{N}{k} x^k\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k = 0}^{N} \binom{N}{k} x^k+\sum_{k = 0}^{N} \binom{N}{k} x^{k+1}\tag{4}\\
> &=\binom{N}{0}x^0+\sum_{k=1}^N\binom{N}{k}x^k+\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\binom{N}{k}x^{k+1}+\binom{N}{N}x^{N+1}\tag{5}\\
> &=\binom{N+1}{0}x^0+\sum_{k=1}^N\binom{N}{k}x^k+\sum_{k=1}^{N}\binom{N}{k-1}x^{k}+\binom{N+1}{N+1}x^{N+1}\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{N+1}\binom{N+1}{k}x^k\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we split the product, since we want to apply the induction hypothesis.
- In (3) we apply the induction hypothesis (1).
- In (4) we multiply out.
- In (5) we separate the first summand $\binom{N}{0}$ from the left sum and the last summand $\binom{N}{N}x^{N+1}$ from the right sum.
- In (6) we use the binomial identities 
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{N}{0}=\binom{N+1}{0}=1\qquad\text{and}\qquad\binom{N}{N}=\binom{N+1}{N+1}=1
  \end{align*}
  We also shift the index $k$ of the right sum by one to start from $k=1$. This all is a preparation for the next step to easily collect all the terms in one sum.
- In (7) we apply the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{N}{k}+\binom{N}{k-1}=\binom{N+1}{k}
  \end{align*}
  and the two sums can be merged into one sum. We also see the left-most term $\binom{N+1}{0}$ and the right-most term $\binom{N+1}{N+1}$ can be made part of the sum using index $k=0$ and $k=N+1$.

Answer (score 1):

We begin with some preliminary theory.

A polynomial in $f(x)$ of degree $n$ can be written in the form

$\tag 1 f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{u+v=n}c_{(u,v)}x^u \quad \text{ where } c_{(u,0)} \ne 0$

and the ordered pairs $(u,v)$ are in $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$.

We have the following

$\tag 2 (1+x) f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{u+v=n+1}c_{(u,v)}x^u \; \text{   where } 
c_{(0,n+1)} = c_{(0,n)} \land c_{(n+1,0)} = c_{(n,0)} \land \big[(u+v= n+1 \land uv \gt 0) \implies c_{(u,v)} = c_{(u-1,v)} + c_{(u,v-1)}\big]$

This is not difficult to understand
(the coefficients are: vertical shifted by $1$ and horizontally shifted by $x$)
or to prove.

Assume we can write as true

$\tag 3
(1 + x)^n = \displaystyle \sum_{u+v=n}c_{(u,v)}x^u \text{ where }  c_{(u,v)} = \binom{n}{u}$

Using $\text{(2)}$ and [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule) it is simple to prove that

$\tag 4
(1 + x)^{n+1} = \displaystyle \sum_{u+v=n+1}c_{(u,v)}x^u \text{ where }  c_{(u,v)} = \binom{n+1}{u}$